# Making a new gist with dynamic filename?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, github-api, gist

I'm trying to create a new gist using the below code (everything works except when I try to make the filename dynamic. Every other variable replacement works except for filename. I can't figure out why it's breaking.

```
var fn = "textfile.txt";
function createGist(token,content,description,shopName,filename){
    $.ajax({ 
        url: 'https://api.github.com/gists',
        type: 'POST',
        beforeSend: function(xhr) { 
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "token " + token); 
        },
        data: JSON.stringify({"description": description,"public": false,"files": {fn: {"content": content }}})
    }).done(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        GM_setValue(shopName,response.id);
    });
}
```

The filename variable the only part of it that's not working (aka replacing it with the actual string works)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `fn` should be the file name. You need to replace:

```
"files": {fn: {"content": content }}}
```

with

```
"files": files
```

where

```
var files = {};
files[filename] = {"content": content};
```

as keys in object literals can't be the value of a variable. In the old code the file name always ends up being `fn`.

For clarification here is the whole code with the proposed changes:

```
var fn = "textfile.txt";
function createGist(token,content,description,shopName,filename){
    var files = {};
    files[filename] = {"content": content};
    $.ajax({ 
        url: 'https://api.github.com/gists',
        type: 'POST',
        beforeSend: function(xhr) { 
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "token " + token); 
        },
        data: JSON.stringify({"description": description,"public": false,"files": files})
    }).done(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        GM_setValue(shopName,response.id);
    });
}
```

Comment: so i can create the entire object separately and pass it through data? since it's multi-level (with the description and such as well)

Comment: Can you give me an example making the rest of the object? I'm not sure if I need to do:
`file['description'] = { "description" : description }`
OR just:
`file['description'] = desciption`
thanks

Comment: @jkingaround No, you don't need to do that, as values in object literals can be the values of variables, so you only need to build the files object as in this answer but the rest of the object can be created as is in the question. See the clarification in the answer.